# Guardar y abrir archivos utilizando JMenu en un canva en java

Tags: java

solicito ayuda urgente, es sobre una tarea, estoy muy desesperada porque no entiendo, si alguien pudiese ayudarme lo agradecería

Este es mi código donde intento guardar un panel canva en un archivo, realmente no los se manejar y por mas que he investigado no logro entenderlos, mi tarea es para hoy a la media noche enserio si alguien pudiese ayudarme le agradecería, también explicarme

```
    public class AccionMenu implements ActionListener {
    
    JMenuItem nuevo, abrir, guardar;
    JMenuBar opciones;
    JMenu menu;
    miPanel panel;
    
    public AccionMenu(JMenuItem nuevo, JMenuItem abrir, JMenuItem guardar, JMenuBar opciones, JMenu menu, miPanel panel) {
        this.nuevo=nuevo;
        this.abrir=abrir;
        this.guardar=guardar;
        this.opciones=opciones;
        this.menu=menu;
        
        nuevo.addActionListener(this);
        abrir.addActionListener(this);
        guardar.addActionListener(this);
        
        menu.add(nuevo);
        menu.add(abrir);
        menu.add(guardar);
        
        this.panel=panel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        
        if(arg0.getSource()==nuevo) {
            panel=null;
            panel=new miPanel();
        }
        
        if(arg0.getSource()==abrir) {
            String nombre= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del archivo")+".TAP";
            System.out.println(nombre);
            
            try {
                ObjectInputStream leyendoFichero = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("objetos.dat") );
                miPanel panel2 = ( miPanel )leyendoFichero.readObject();
                leyendoFichero.close();
                
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
            
        }
        
        if(arg0.getSource()==guardar) {
            String nombre= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del archivo")+".TAP";
            System.out.println(nombre);
            
            try {
                 ObjectOutputStream escribiendoFichero = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(nombre) );
                 escribiendoFichero.writeObject(panel);
                 escribiendoFichero.close();
                 System.out.println("ok");
                
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Aquí no se venden tareas y espero que podamos ayudarte con tu problema. Mientras tanto, es necesario que añadas a la pregunta qué es lo que falla en ese código, por qué dices que no funciona, etc. [Edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/427435/edit) y añade esa info (con el enlace Editar que está debajo de la pregunta)

Comment: Y esta vez, a diferencia de tus dos preguntas anteriores, es importante que sigas las recomendaciones en los comentarios y procures aceptar alguna de las respuestas o indiques cómo lo resolviste tú misma. Ver que no te ocupas por interactuar con las respuestas que te dan (o los comentarios) desanima a los que puedan considerar ayudarte. Resolver problemas de programación es un diálogo :)